# Woocommerce Subscriptions: Stop manual renewals from going on hold

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When Manual Renewals are selected in the Woocommerce Subscription options, the system will put the invoices automatically on-hold until they are paid.

We would like to give our customers more time to pay, meaning that we need the system to continue to output invoices even when the subscription already has one unpaid invoice created. Our thought was to have the system set the invoices to processing instead of on-hold. Open to other ideas as well.

Any ideas on how best to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to address your concern to the plugin author: https://github.com/Prospress